# Numerical Approximation Rules

Tags: calculus, approximation-theory

I was not exactly sure what to title this question, but I would appreciate if someone can confirm my understanding of the left hand, right hand, trapezoidal, midpoint, and simpsons approximations.

It is my understanding that if the Curve is **INCREASING**:

Left Hand Approximation: Underestimates

Right Hand Approximation: Overestimates

**DECREASING**:

Left Hand Approximation: Overestimates

Right Hand Approximation: Underestimates

**CONCAVE UP**:

Midpoint Approximation: Underestimates

Trapezoidal Approximation: Overestimates

**CONCAVE DOWN**:

Midpoint Approximation: Overestimates

Trapezoidal Approximation: Underestimates

I am not sure of any rules like these exist for Simpson's rule, so if you could inform me if there is a simple trick, as well as confirm my understanding of these approximations and if the rules are true. Thank you.

Comment: What you've written looks right to me – but math isn't meant to be a bunch of rules to be memorized, it's meant to be a bunch of logical deductions to be understood. I hope you understand *why* midpoint underestimates concave up, and so on. Simpson estimates by areas under parabolas, while the others use straight lines, so if there's a rule for Simpson, it's bound to be more complicated.